# Oracle Apex - How to fire a POST request to an external service while saving records in apex db

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2, oracle-apex-19.1

I have an application where I am capturing few values in a form and I am trying to save them in Database at the same time I want to trigger a rest post request with those attributes .
How to achieve this in oracle apex ? Should I write a db trigger for this
?

Comment: Please do NOT do anything in a trigger that is not part of a transaction. Firstly, any external call will be taking some time, with possible timeouts and you would not want to keep a transaction running for a long time. Secondly, and this is of a bigger concern, triggers are NOT guaranteed to run ONLY ONCE. Under certain circumstances a single trigger could be run twice, thrice etc for the same row in that same transaction, that's why an external call could be run multiple times

Comment: Hi akhi, did you still need help with this or did Koen’s answer work? If it worked, please accept the answer for future viewers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible. Put the code in a page process with same condition as your row processing. To invoke a rest request via pl/sql you can use  `apex_web_service.make_rest_request`, documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/apex_web_service.htm#AEAPI1965)

db triggers *could* be a solution but should be avoided in my opinion. Supposed you create an on-update trigger that fires the rest request and then a DBA comes a long and runs an update statement that affects all rows but forgets to disable the trigger... that means that this rest request will be re-executed for every single row... .

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit on the approach 1? what you mean by "put code in page and process with same condition"?
How can I put a pl/sql code in an apex page ? Please guide me here

Comment: Page processes are a basic part of apex. It is where you run pl/sql at a processing point (in your case on submit) What is it you need help with ?